# Receive data from USB device

Tags: java, android, usb

I try to send command to my usb device and get response. It's an custom scanner. I have connection with it and thats works fine. What I need to do now is to send command DA AD 02 74 00 to turn on the device. I define command like this :

```
private final byte[] send = new byte[]{
                (byte) 0xDA, (byte) 0xAD,  // const
                (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x74, (byte) 0x00, // com

        };
```

I have UsbConnector.class where I set connection and do other strange things. I also have two methods there to send and receive data :

```
 public int send(byte[] bytes) {
       return currentUsbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(currentUsbEndpointOut, bytes, bytes.length, SEND_TIMEOUT);


}


public byte[] receive(int length) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
    int result = currentUsbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(currentUsbEndpointIn, bytes, bytes.length, RECEIVE_TIMEOUT);
    if (result >= 0) {
        return bytes;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I want to make send data after clicking button so it goes like this :

```
mTestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                UsbConnector connector = new UsbConnector(getApplicationContext(), device, listener);
                connector.run();
                connector.send(send);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "BYTE" + send, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mRunning = true;
                while (mRunning) {
                    byte[] received = connector.receive(36);
                    if (received == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mRunning=false;
                    }
                    if (received != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NIE NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mRunning=false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

But still I'm getting null at received. Please, help :/